# How do I escape characters in an RSS feed?

Tags: fieldtype, rss, html-entities, wyvern

Here's a link to [my RSS feed's failed validation](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http://www.terry.uga.edu/rss/terry-sound-business#l225). Nevermind the subtitles being too long, I'll fix that later. But fixing these special characters is a pill and in company names where it's part of their brand fixture, I can't readily change "&" to "and". How can I escape these characters? In the channel entry, the channel field type is sometimes Wyvern (already escaped the HTML character) and sometimes simply Text Input, which I believe is plain text right?

Comment: could you please post your template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

unexplainedBacn is right.

Or you can also use the **XML Encode** plugin for this. It's actually included with ExpressionEngine

> This plugin converts reserved XML characters to entities. It is used
>   in the RSS templates.
>
> To use this plugin, wrap anything you want to be processed by it
>   between these tag pairs:
>
> ```
> {exp:xml_encode}
>     text you want processed
> {/exp:xml_encode}
> ```

To see more on usage go to Add-ons > Plugins > XML Encode in your EE Control Panel.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you could wrap the offending content in [`<![CDATA[{content}]]>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CDATASection) tags.

Like so:

```
<description>
<![CDATA[
{body}
]]>
</description>
```

This won't actually escape the characters, but it will tell the validator to not worry about it.